# EasyBatch with Xml Reader, Xml Writer and processor

Tags: java, easy-batch

I’m trying using EasyBatch instead of Spring batch to see if I can remove some overhead. I have the use case as

**Input file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GroupRuleOutputs>
                <GroupRuleOutput doc_id="str1234" copy_num="str1234" copy_id="str1234">
                                <GroupRule>
                                                <ReturnCode>123</ReturnCode>
<Data></Data>
                                </GroupRule>
                </GroupRuleOutput>

                <GroupRuleOutput doc_id="str1234" copy_num="str1234" copy_id="str1234">
                                <GroupRule>
                                                <ReturnCode>ABC</ReturnCode>
<Data></Data>
                                </GroupRule>
                </GroupRuleOutput>
</GroupRuleOutputs>
```

**The expected output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GroupRuleOutputs>
                <GroupRuleOutput doc_id="str1234" copy_num="str1234" copy_id="str1234">
                                <GroupRule>
                                                <ReturnCode>123</ReturnCode>
<Data>123 from API</Data>
                                </GroupRule>
                </GroupRuleOutput>

                <GroupRuleOutput doc_id="str1234" copy_num="str1234" copy_id="str1234">
                                <GroupRule>
                                                <ReturnCode>ABC</ReturnCode>
<Data>ABC from API</Data>
                                </GroupRule>
                </GroupRuleOutput>
</GroupRuleOutputs>
```

We need to populate Data field based on ReturnCode by calling an API to get information.

I have built an application which have done the job but there are still something I would like to ask

Here is my code to make the app works

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name="GroupRuleOutput")
public class GroupRuleOutput {

   @XmlElement(name="GroupRule")
   private GroupRule groupRule;
}

File groupRuleOutputFile = new File("c:\\work\\temp\\sample.xml");
File mergedGroupRuleOutputFile = new File("c:\\work\\temp\\output.xml");

Job job = JobBuilder.aNewJob()
        .reader(new XmlFileRecordReader(groupRuleOutputFile, "GroupRuleOutput"))
        .mapper(new XmlRecordMapper(GroupRuleOutput.class))
        .processor(new GroupRuleOutputMergeProcessor())
        .marshaller(new XmlRecordMarshaller(GroupRuleOutput.class))
        .writer(new FileRecordWriter(new FileWriter(mergedGroupRuleOutputFile)))
        .build();

JobExecutor jobExecutor = new JobExecutor();
jobExecutor.execute(job);
jobExecutor.shutdown();


public class GroupRuleOutputMergeProcessor implements RecordProcessor {
   @Override
   public Record processRecord(Record record) throws Exception {
      GroupRuleOutput groupRuleOutput = (GroupRuleOutput)record.getPayload();
      groupRuleOutput.getGroupRule().setReturnCode("I change " + groupRuleOutput.getGroupRule().getReturnCode());
      return record;
   }
}
```

**Here are my questions**

Is my configuration of Reader, mapper, marcheller and writer are
    correct or not? This is the first time I’m trying EasyBatch.

Do we need to have mapper and marshaller here? I guess yes but just to
    make sure. And does it impact to performance

Do we have any XmlWriter in EasyBatch?

Do we have any way to configure the Processor with Type specific ? Currently I have to case from Payload to my Pojo If we have a lot of entries,

Could we integrate Spring Bean in Processor class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is my configuration of Reader, mapper, marcheller and writer are correct or not? This is the first time I’m trying EasyBatch.

Yes, your configuration is correct.

> Do we need to have mapper and marshaller here? I guess yes but just to make sure. And does it impact to performance

No, those are not necessary. But it is better to map raw xml input to domain object in order to manipulate objects instead of strings. As per performance, it will depend on your xml marshalling library.

> Do we have any XmlWriter in EasyBatch?

No. there is a `FileRecordWriter` that takes a string (without being aware of its format) and writes it to a file. It is up to you to marshal the string upfront with a `RecordMarshaller` to JSON, XML, CSV, etc.

> Do we have any way to configure the Processor with Type specific ? Currently I have to case from Payload to my Pojo If we have a lot of entries,

Yes. The `Record` and `RecordProcessor` APIs are generic.

> Could we integrate Spring Bean in Processor class?

Yes, please take a look at this [FAQ](https://github.com/j-easy/easy-batch/wiki/faqs#7-can-i-use-easy-batch-with-spring)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works for me. I have a question if we use easybatch-spring, are we paying off any performance?

Comment: Another question I may have is, when I can a job using JobBuilder, if I don't need any jms, monitoring , ... could we disable them to gain some performance?